# VueJS bootstrap scss importing into child single file component vue files with <style lang="scss">

Tags: vue.js, webpack, bootstrap-5, sass-loader

I am currently working on a project created by @vue/cli (vue-cli).  I have integrated bootstrap v5 and imported its SASS file into my
main entry point because I have some color customizations to alter.

I have some

```
<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

blocks in single file components (.vue files) which I would like to access bootstrap sass variables (for example, $primary). So for example

Widget.vue

```
....
<style lang="scss">
   .my-class {
     color: $primary;
   }
</style>
```

With just this, the build fails with 'undefined variable'.  A simple solution would be to @import my custom bootstrap sass file into each
vue single file component where I will be references sass variables
Widget.vue

```
...
<style lang="scss">
   @import '~@/assets/bootstrap-custom.scss'
   .my-class {
      color: $primary;
   }
</style>
```

This works HOWEVER the resulting bundle will import bootstrap for every @import statement it encounters resulting in multiple  tags.

Another solution has floated around configuring the css loader as so

```
{ 
  css: { 
    loaderOptions: { 
      sass: { 
        additionalData: `@import '~@/asserts/bootstrap-custom.scss';`,
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

No longer am I required to @import manually with this change however this is even worse in that every `<style lang="scss">` defined in a vue file will result in a complete
reimport (extra style tag) copied resulting in longer build time and an inefficient bundle

Is there a way to have a single import of bootstrap/my custom bootsrap stuff which all scss style section can see?